# Limit the scope of a variable passed over within comma-separated expressions

Tags: javascript

I build a function that uses comma-separated expressions within its body and certain variable passed over between those expressions, like:

```js
let y = 3;
const square = x => (y = x ** 2, y);
console.log(square(2), y);
```

*I know, I can simply do `x => x**2`, above code is used only for the sake of example*

The problem to me is that `y` is declared within global scope (which I wouldn't like to clutter up) and I can access that outside of the `square` body (e.g. `console.log(y)`);

My first suspicion was it's the arrow syntax issue, but

```js
let y = 3;
function square2(x) {
  return (y = x ** 2, y)
};
console.log(square2(2), y);
```

results in the same issue.
I have also tried to limit the scope of `y`:

```js
let y = 3;
const square = x => (const y = x ** 2, y);
console.log(square(2), y);
```

And it throws

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token const

Just as expected.
So, my question is:

- is there a way to limit the scope of the variable declared within such context;
- or is there some other way to pass the data over between expressions;
- or thre's no issue at all and above construction is absolutely eligible

?

Comment: If you want to prevent implicit globals, then you have to declare the variable locally. If you declare the variable locally, you can't use the comma operator, as it requires you to do further declarations. So you can't use both a comma operator and a new variable declaration at the same time on one line, you need to do a multi-line function.

Comment: Include it in the parameter list: `let square = (x, y) => (y = x**2, y)`.

Comment: @RobG : and that will work for user-defined functions, I can't use this trick with some methods, like `Array.prototype.map()`, right? Is there a workaround for the latter as well?

Comment: Why wont it work with *map*? `arr.map((x, y) => (y = x**2, y))` works for me. Though I've yet to be convinced that it's a good idea.

Comment: @RobG 's suggestion should solve the problem as it would be a different scope

Comment: @RobG : So, you're basically overriding expected index as a second parameter or even, may pass around one extra parameter (if needed). That's a really nice trick. Post that as an answer and I'll accept that.

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. What is the exact purpose of this? Because in @RobG 's proposal, a local variable is introduced which isn't read within the function, nor can it be accessed outside of it. Is this just about putting the code into a single line?

Comment: @Codekie indeed, this seems like trying to bend over backwards just to just avoid having two lines. Which you can already do if you have  `x => { const y = x ** 2; return y; }` - it's still one line if you don't have the newlines and (assuming the real expression is short enough), it's perfectly readable. Or at least as readable as using a comma operator.

Comment: `x => [x,y].map((x, y) => (y = x**2, y))[0]`, `square = x => { const y = x ** 2; return y; }`, `(x, y) => (y = x**2, y)` would be the possible solutions to adopt